# select uppercase letter from string and convert them into character array

Tags: java, string

How can I convert a string into a character Array but with one twist: only the upper case letters should be put in the character array.

***For example***,

- **input string**: `"abCcAB123"`
- **output char array**: `{C,A,B}`

Comment: Can you post some code what you tried ?

Comment: Remove the lowercased letter first (e.g. using a regex), then use toCharArray().

Comment: Vote for close since OPs lack of effort.

Comment: get string into char array then filter out the lowercases, you will have upper cases char. Now write this in code !

Comment: `char[] result = s.toUpperCase().toCharArray();`

Comment: @sp00m or, alternatively, remove everthing that's not an upper case letter, depending on whether non-letter characters should be kept.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera... i have tried it by first converting string into array name it array1 then make another array array2 now in array1 number whose ASCII values are between 65-90 send it to array2...it works but i want another optimize code(small code) which require less time so i asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s="ab !@#$&*()//CcAB897987";
         List upperChar=new ArrayList();
         String a = s.replaceAll( "[^A-Z\\-]", "" );  // remove all character other Uppercase character
         char []ch=a.toCharArray();              // this contains all uppercase character
         for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
               upperChar.add(ch[i]);             // make a list of uppercase char.
         }

           System.out.println(upperChar);

 }
```

output :

```
[C, A, B]
```

Comment: i have tried your code but it just removes lower case but other key-letter like number remains there

Comment: then put `[a-z0-9]` instead of `[a-z]`

Comment: [a-z0-9] removes lowercase and number from string but special character like "!@#" are still there in array so will you please give code to remove all special character

Answer (score 1):

Rmove all non uppercase letters and then convert to char array.

```
String str = "abCcAB";
String a = str.replaceAll( "[^A-Z]", "" );
System.out.println(a.toCharArray());
```

Comment: i have tried your code but it just removes lower case but other key-letter like number remains there

Comment: Which string have you tried. I dont see why any number sould remain.

Comment: i have tried string "abCcAB123"

Answer (score 0):

psedocode:

```
    queue output; //declaration of the character array for output
    while(input.length!=0){ //checking the length of the input array
        firstcharacter=string.charAt(0); //getting the firstCharacter of the input string
        if(character.IsUpperCase(firtcharacter)){ //checking if the firstCharacter is uppercase
            output.enqueue(firtcharacter); //if the character is uppercase add to the array
        }
        input=input.substring(1,string.length); //remove the first character from the string
    }
//output should now contain all the uppercase characters.
```

This is the logic behind solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public class CaptialChars {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String input="SaGaR";
        char[] output=input.replaceAll("[a-z]", "").toCharArray();
        for(char character:output){
            System.out.println(character);
        }

    }
}
```